# How to horizontaly format form with input group addon using FluentBootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentbootstrap

I am trying to create labeled input while the input is decorated with an icon. There is also a help text which should show under the input. This is a sample also including simple input at the bottom which works fine.

```
@using (var form = Html.Bootstrap().Form().SetHorizontal(2).Begin())
{
    @using (var group = b.FormGroup().SetHorizontal(true).Begin())
    {
        @group.ControlLabel(m => m.Amount)
        using (var inputGroup = b.InputGroup().Begin())
        {
            @inputGroup.InputGroupAddon("@")
            @inputGroup.InputFor(m => m.Amount)
        }
        @b.HelpBlock("Help description")
    }

    @b.InputFor(m => m.MaxDurationMonths).AddChildAtEnd(x => x.HelpBlock("Another help."))
}
```

For some reason the label is put inside the input group (for the decorated input) and not the form group. Therefore I cannot achieve horizontal layout for this form group. I tried to SetAutoColumns(false) on the group but I cannot format the InputGroupAddon nor HelpBlock using SetMd. Also this input is then not aligned with the reference input which is working fine. Is there a way to do it correctly?
Thanks for help!

Edit: this is how it looks on screen
[input group addon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx928.png)